# Removing html tags without plugin using regex

Tags: java, regex

So I'm trying to remove every section that contains html tags accept for `<p></p>` in java.

I tried this accept I can't get the closing tag correct do I have. I tried (///p) and can't seem to catch it.

```
"<[^(p>)>]+>.*?<[^(///p>)>]+>"
```

Example

```
<p> should stay </p> <html> shouldn't stay</html>
```

Output

```
<p> should stay </p>
```

Comment: Are there nested tags? What would be result of `<p><b>foo</b></p>` or `<div><p>bar</p></div>`?

Comment: I believe I'm legally required to post this at least once: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/421784

Comment: I'll just put that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?rq=1

Comment: Ah I see 
@Pshemo first cast should stay in whole and second case should be remove in whole

Comment: So nested tags are possible. In that case regex is not good for your requirement. Lets say that you have `<div><p><div>X</div></p><p>Y</p></div>` regex would remove from first `<div>` to first `</div>` so you would get as result `</p><p>Y</p></div>`. You should consider using parser instead of regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using regexes to manipulate HTML is a bad, bad, bad idea.  Using regexes to parse HTML/XML will summon Cthulu.  Your soul will be eaten by Cthulu.  Cthulu's other name is RegexHtmlParser.

You're better off using xpath to extract all the paragraph tags.  Otherwise, an HTML parser that will allow you to walk the DOM and pull out the paragraph tags are your only real choices.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?page=1&tab=active#tab-top says it all :]

Comment: If double upvoting wasn't against the rules, I would just have done it right now. Perhaps http://www.marlborotech.com/Zalgo.html is of some use ;)